# Backbone.js: convert this coffeescript into jquery

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to learn how to use backbone.js. Problem is that a tutorial I'm following (the Railscast) is using coffeescript, and I'd rather use jquery. I know how to change a function in coffeescript to jquery, but I didn't know what to change about this definition of a route

```
   routes:
   '': 'index'
```

Am I supposed to put brackets around it? The alert's not working, so I'm assuming something's wrong with the definition of the route.

This was the original coffeescript

```
Backboner.Routers.Entries = Backbone.Router.extend


       routes:
       '': 'index'

       index: ->

        alert "homepage"
```

javascript/jquery

```
Backboner.Routers.Entries = Backbone.Router.extend({


   routes:
   '': 'index'

   index: function(){

    alert("homepage");
   }
});
```

Update: I made the changes that were suggested but the alert's not appearing.

Javascripts/Backboner.js

```
window.Backboner = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  init: function() {
    new Backboner.Routers.Entries();
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};
```

Javascripts/routers/entries.js

```
Backboner.Routers.Entries = Backbone.Router.extend({

   routes: {
   '': 'index'
    },


   index: function(){

    return alert('homepage');
   }
});
```

Second update:

Putting document ready into file

```
window.Backboner = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  init: function() {
    new Backboner.Routers.Entries();
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return Backboner.init();
});
```

third update

the manifest file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require backboner
//= require_tree ../templates/
//= require_tree .//models
//= require_tree .//collections
//= require_tree .//views
//= require_tree .//routers
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you are supposed to put curly braces around it. In the future, you can convert from CoffeeScript to Javascript right on [CoffeeScript.org](http://coffeescript.org/) by clicking "Try CoffeeScript". Paste in the CoffeeScript and you will see the Javascript output.

Keep in mind, CoffeeScript has **significant** white space, so your original question was incorrectly formatted. It should have been:

```
Backbone.Routers.Entries = Backbone.Router.extend

       routes:
         '': 'index'

       index: ->

         alert "homepage"
```

which using the CoffeeScript website gives:

```
Backbone.Routers.Entries = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index'
  },
  index: function() {
    return alert("homepage");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes that you suggested, but the alert's not appearing. I updated the OP. Do you know why the alert's not showing when I navigate to the index?

Comment: You are calling Backboner.history.start(), not Backbone.history.start()

Comment: ok, i changed it to Backbone.history.start() but it's still not working.

Comment: And are you calling Backboner.init() somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure that the code that defines Backboner.Routers.Entries is being called before you init? What is the result when you new it up in your init() call? Have you stepped through the code using Firebug or something similar?

Comment: It's telling me that 'TypeError: Backboner.Routers.Entries is not a constructor' and also TypeError: Backbone.Routers is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

index: function() {  . However, I don't know how to step through Backbone with firebug

Comment: Do you have a link to backbone.js before any of your code that extends Router is executed? Backbone.Routers doesn't exist but Backbone.Router does btw.

Comment: I updated the OP with the manifest file, showing that backbone.js is required before the other files.  What's the point of your remark that Backbone.Routers doesn't exist. Should I be using Backbone.Router?

Comment: I got it. I chose a bad name for the app, too confusing. It should be Backboner.Routers  (with an r)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I want to quickly go back and forth between the two for a confusing situation I will use this tool... It at least makes an attempt at automated Javascript -> CoffeeScript conversion.

[Use js2coffee.org at your own risk :)](http://js2coffee.org)

Of course for Coffeescript -> Javascript you can just use the coffeescript website.